# How to create a toggle stream in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, events, observable, rxjs

I'd like to create a steam that toggles based on `keyup` and `keydown`. The key code is emitted once on a `keydown` event and emitted again on the `keyup` event. I used `distinctUntilChanged` to prevent multiple key codes from being sent while `keydown` fires. The problem with my code is that I can't do successive `keydown` and `keyup` on the same key code because of the `distinctUntilChanged`.

Currently, pressing and releasing 'a' followed by 'b' works, but not 'a' followed by 'a'.

### Requirements

What I want to achieve is:

- when the key is down, do some task
- when the key is up, stop doing that task
- multiple keys can be down or up (so can't use the `keypress` event)
- different actions are associated with different keys (think of 'a' for action-1 and 'b' for action-2)

### Code

```
var getKeyCode = function(e) { return e.which; }
var target = document.querySelector('body');

var keyDownStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(target, 'keydown')
    .distinctUntilChanged(getKeyCode);

var keyUpStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(target, 'keyup')
    .distinctUntilChanged(getKeyCode);

var toggleStream = Rx.Observable.merge(keyDownStream, keyUpStream);

toggleStream.subscribe(function(e) {
    console.log(e.which);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution was to move the `distinctUntilChanged` to the merged observable and filter by event type and keycode. This would ensure that the subscribers are notified once for the `keydown` event and once for the `keyup` event for the same key.

```
var filterByTypeAndKeyCode = function(e) { return e.type + e.which; }
var target = document.querySelector('body');
var keyUpStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(target, 'keyup');
var keyDownStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(target, 'keydown');

Rx.Observable.merge(keyDownStream, keyUpStream)
    .distinctUntilChanged(filterByTypeAndKeyCode)
    .subscribe(function(e) {
        console.log(e.which);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I used:

```
var toggleStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.body, 'keydown').filter(function ( e, index ) {
  return index < 1;
}).takeUntil(Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.body, 'keyup')).repeat();

toggleStream.subscribe(function ( e ) {
 // the task should go here 
 console.log("key down :" + e.which);
});
```

You can find a jsbin here : http://jsbin.com/xuqasawese/edit?html,js,console,output

Currently, pressing and releasing 'a' followed by 'b' works, and also 'a' followed by 'a'. However, you can imagine that you press key 'a' and without releasing that key, press another one 'b' and release 'b'. Then press another key 'c', and your action will be executed. It's kind of an edge case, but do you have any intended behaviour should that happen?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I forgot to add that to the use case. I did want to be able to register multiple keys down at the same time to execute different code for each key.